# Текст в одну строчку

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Есть строки такого типа:

```
*Number:Date // То есть тут начало, где есть символ *
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
*Number:Date //  То есть тут начало, где есть символ *
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
Number:Date
*Number:Date //  То есть тут начало, где есть символ *
Number:Date
Number:Date
```

Нужно их склеить все одну строчку **от символа * и между склеенными строками поставить двоеточие :** На выходе должно получится:

```
*Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date
*Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date
*Number:Date:Number:Date:Number:Date
```

Даже в голову не приходит как такое реализовать ? Можно делать что то в роде этого

```
s:=s1+':'+s2; + ....
```

Но до реализации так и не дошло, не хватило знаний.

Comment: Строки в стринг листе?

Comment: @zed, Можно и так мне просто бы посмотреть реализацию.

Comment: Цикл по списку с конкатенацией и вставкой двоеточия во временную переменную, как только встретится символ `*` в i-ой строке списка, сохранять значение временной переменной в новый список.

Comment: @zed, Спасибо буду пробовать. Если получится выложу готовый код.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, вот ответ если кому будет интересно:

```
begin
  with TStringList.Create do begin
    Assign(Memo1.Lines);
    Text := StringReplace(Text, #13#10, ';', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Text := StringReplace(Text, '*', #13#10 + '*', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Memo2.Text :=  Trim(Text);
    Free;
  end;
end;
```